How to prove this functional-differential inequality?

Let $f(x)$ be a function from $C^3( \mathbb{R} )$ satisfying the following conditions for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$: $$f(x)<0, f'(x)>0, f''(x)<0, f'''(x)>0, 27f'''(x)+f(x) \leq 0.$$ Prove that $3f'(x)+2f(x)<0$.

Source. This problem is from mathematical competition in Moscow that was held in 2023.
My attempt.

I tried to make a substitution $f(x)=g(\frac{x}{3})$ $\big($then $27f'''(x)=g'''(\frac{x}{3}) \big)$.
I also tried to use somehow that $0>f'f \Rightarrow 0>f^2(x)-f^2(0)$ and the same for $f'f''<0$ and $f''f'''<0$.
I denoted
$$h(x)=3f'(x)+2f(x) \tag{*}$$ and reduced the problem to proving $h(x)<0$, where $f$ may be found as
$$f(x)=e^{-\frac{2x}{3}}\left(f(0)+\frac{1}{3} \int_{0}^{x}e^{\frac{2t}{3}}h(t)dt \right).$$ Moreover from $(*)$ we have $f=-\frac{3}{2}f'+\frac{1}{2}h(x)<0$ and thus $h(x)<3f'(x)$ $\big($same for $f'=-\frac{3}{2}f''+\frac{1}{2}h'(x)>0$ and further for $f''...\big)$, but that wasn't successfully.

I don't know what an expression/identity/substitution I should guess to solve the problem. Help me please

Just in case it might help with finding the right path to the solution, where did you find this problem? For example, was it a contest question?

@BrunoB this problem is from mathematical competition in Moscow that was held in 2023

I forgot which one - but one year of the IMC has a very similar problem.

@dezdichado I saw all the problems from the IMC from every year and I don't remember anything that might be really useful to solve this problem

@pioo hmmm I must have misremembered then - apologies for the mislead. But I definitely have seen the first four of the five requirements on $f$ on a problem somewhere.

Let $f(x)=-\exp g(x)$ and $h(x)=1/g'(x)$. Then the conditions are equivalent to $$h(x)<0,\quad h'(x)<1,\quad\frac{h(x)^3}{27}\le h(x)h''(x)-2h'(x)^2+3h'(x)-1<0$$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$ and we wish to show that $h(x)<-3/2$.

As @dezdichado remembered, this is a near-duplicate of question B4 in the
1999 Putnam exam, which is already answered here on MSE or here on the Putnam website.
Here are the details.
Put $g(t)=-f(-3t)$. Then $g^{(k)}(t)=-(-3)^kf^{(k)}(-3t)$, and hence $g,g',g''$ and $g'''$
are all nonnegative.
Condition $f(x)+27f'''(x) \leq 0$ is equivalent to $g(t)\geq g'''(t)$.
Condition $3f'(x)+2f(x) \lt 0$ is equivalent to $g'(t)\leq 2g(t)$.
But, by any of the linked answers above, we indeed do have $g'(t) \leq 2g(t)$, qed.
